# how to freez header in a table in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I have one table, i want to fix that header while scrolling

**JS**

```
<script>
$('#scroll').scroll(function(){
if ($('#scroll').scrollTop() > 10){
    $("thead").css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '68px'
        });
}else{
    $('thead').css({
        position: 'static'
    });
}
});
</script>
```

This is working Perfectly, but design is changing.

`LIVE DEMO - http://testing.twomini.com/`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqDC5/)

could anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post the same question hours after you put the first one on the site. For that matter don't post the same question ever. Your just wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position to 'static'

```
$("thead").css({
    position: 'static',
    top: '68px'
});
```